# docker compose backup bitnami redmine volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redmine, bitnami

I started a [bitnami redmine container](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine) (via docker-compose), logged in to redmine and created one user.

What's the procedure to backup/restore the system at this point?

I would like to be able to do a fresh `docker-compose up` afterwards but using the backup volume, the one which has the user I created.

I tried to backup the volume folder (/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_mariadb_data) and then replace it in the new container but this procedure didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can backup your DB using `mysqldump`

```
docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

This will produce a backup on your host system. You can then mount the data so the `mysql` image will import it, create the DB, and ingest the data on initial creation of the DB container.

See the `mysql` Docker image documentation:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

> #### Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data.

Comment: Ok, got it. But the bitnami redmine container (https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine) uses MariaDB (https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb) which don't appear to have the same initialization mechanism. Is there any way around MariaDB?

Comment: Anyway, this (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Migrate_Redmine_to_a_new_server_to_a_new_Redmine_version) was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup/restore your bitnami redmine container by [persisting volumes](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine#persisting-your-application).

Just replace 'mariadb_data' and 'redmine_data' in your docker-compose.yml with the local directories where you want the data to be persisted.